# How to raise/lower sound and brightness using keyboard only?

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-surface-pro-3

When I press <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd>, I can mute the whole system. However, I can't see any keys for volume up/down. How do I do that?

I can see the keys for brightness but when I invoke them, the brightness doesn't change. What can I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

1. Hold down the "Fn" key.
2. Press either the "UP" arrow key or the "RIGHT" arrow key to increase brightness. Depending on your keyboard, one will likely be brightness (the one with the sun on it) and the other will be contrast.
3. Press either the "DOWN" arrow key or the "LEFT" arrow key to turn down the brightness. As before, only one of these will adjust the brightness (the one with the sun on it) the other will change the contrast.

Comment: None of the combination seems to affect contrast, brightness nor sound. Please note that the question includes the sound volume as well. The only keys with bright/dark symbol are F1 and F2 and pressing those doesn't affect anything, neither...